# The port has been being used error on an UDP connection

Tags: go, sockets, networking, udp

I have been developing an application to send files between two computers. I use Golang.

The error
`udp listen 0.0.0.0:12345: bind: Normally only one usage is allowed per socket address (communication management/network address/port).`

This is a function to take file from a client. First loop is for the function to work always. Second loop is for that if a problem occurs, it will try to listen forever. Third loop is to take whole files bytes, its name and a value for EOF. I do not know if the if statement which is for EOF works. Actually, i want to create a file for file which will be sent by the client if there is no file named the name of the file. I'll do it.

```
func take_file() {
    udp_address, address_error := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:" + port)
    if address_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(address_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    
    for {
        var connection net.UDPConn
        for {
            new_connection, connection_error := net.ListenUDP("udp", udp_address)
            if connection_error != nil {
                fmt.Println(connection_error.Error())
                continue
            } else {
                connection = *new_connection
                break
            }
        }
        defer connection.Close()

        
        for {
            datas := make([]byte, buffer)
            n, _, reading_error := connection.ReadFromUDP(datas)
            if reading_error != nil {
                fmt.Println(reading_error.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            if string(datas[:n]) == EOF {
                break
            }

            fmt.Println(string(datas[:n]))
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function to send a file to a server. I used the loops with the same intentions like the function of take file's.

```
func send_file(file_path, receiver_ip string) {
    udp_address, address_error := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", receiver_ip + ":" + port)
    if address_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(address_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {
        var connection net.UDPConn
        for {
            new_connection, connection_error := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, udp_address)
            if connection_error != nil {
                fmt.Println(connection_error.Error())
                continue
            } else {
                connection = *new_connection
                break
            }
        }
        defer connection.Close()

        //file name extracter
        file_name := file_name_extracter(file_path)
        
        _, writing_error := connection.Write([]byte(file_name))
        if writing_error != nil {
            fmt.Println(writing_error.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        //function to send files as divided parts
        read_file_and_send(file_path, connection)

        _, writing_error = connection.Write([]byte(EOF))
        if writing_error != nil {
            fmt.Println(writing_error.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function to a read file by dividing it as parts. I divide file size with buffer and i read the file as result. Besides, i read the file as buffer in second loop and send it to the server. I just wanted to send the file as parts.

```
func read_file_and_send(file_path string, connection net.UDPConn) {
    file_info, info_error := os.Stat(file_path)
    if info_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(info_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //file size as byte
    file_size := file_info.Size()

    file, opening_error := os.Open(file_path)
    if opening_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(opening_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    //calculation for loops and packages
    //it will divide file byte number with buffer amount and it will send packages by using the result
    //it will send bytes as buffer size from index 0 to index buffer
    //after that it will send bytes between buffer amount and buffer * 2
    //it will send bytes like that
    package_number := file_size / buffer
    quantity := buffer
    j := 0
    var i int64
    i = 0
    file_reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for i < package_number {
        buffer := make([]byte, buffer)

        for j < quantity {
            byte, reading_error := file_reader.ReadByte()
            if reading_error != nil {
                fmt.Println(reading_error.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            buffer = append(buffer, byte)           
            fmt.Println(buffer)
            j++
        }
        
        connection.Write(buffer)

        i++
        quantity *= 2
    }
}
```

When i run the function to send, i see this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR0Y0.png)

Comment: Why are you dereferencing the `*UDPConn`? That should only be handled as a pointer. You are calling `defer` in a for loop, which isn't closing the connection when you need to have it closed, but why keep re-opening the listener repeatedly in the loop to begin with?

Comment: when i make net.UDPConn pointer, i get "connection declared and not used" error

Comment: chatGPT solved it

Comment: @shiva13, If you figured out the solution you should post that answer here. Second, ChatGPT is an awful source of answers to programming questions. The code it provides is frequently incorrect or not idiomatic.

Comment: @KurtisRader I don't know but it solved.

Answer (score -1):

I have removed first loop from "send_file" function. The latest appearence of it:

```
func send_file(file_path, receiver_ip, port string) {
    udp_address, address_error := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", receiver_ip + ":" + port)
    if address_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(address_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var connection *net.UDPConn
    var connection_error error
    for {
        connection, connection_error = net.DialUDP("udp", nil, udp_address)         
        if connection_error != nil {
            fmt.Println(connection_error.Error())
            continue
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    //file name extracter
    file_name := file_name_extracter(file_path)
        
    _, writing_error := connection.Write([]byte(file_name))
    if writing_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(writing_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //function to send files as divided parts
    read_file_and_send(file_path, connection)

    _, writing_error = connection.Write([]byte(EOF))
    if writing_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(writing_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I have changed read_file_and_send function too.

```
func read_file_and_send(file_path string, connection *net.UDPConn) {
    file_info, info_error := os.Stat(file_path)
    if info_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(info_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //file size as byte
    file_size := file_info.Size()

    file, opening_error := os.Open(file_path)
    if opening_error != nil {
        fmt.Println(opening_error.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    //calculation for loops and packages
    //it will divide file byte number with buffer amount and it will send packages by using the result
    //it will send bytes as buffer size from index 0 to index buffer
    //after that it will send bytes between buffer amount and buffer * 2
    //it will send bytes like that
    conclusion := file_size / buffer
    package_number := number_ceil(conclusion) //this is for decimal number, i am supposed to prevent it

    quantity := buffer

    var i int64
    i = 0
    file_reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for i < package_number {
        j := 0
        bytes := make([]byte, 0)

        for j < quantity {
            byte, reading_error := file_reader.ReadByte()
            if reading_error != nil {
                fmt.Println(reading_error.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            bytes = append(bytes, byte)

            j++
        }

        connection.Write(bytes)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).